# Android: "change/intercept network settings and traffic" permission

Tags: android, android-networking

There is a "change/intercept network settings and traffic" permission listed in some Android apps, ex: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nqmobile.antivirus20&hl=en

But from the latest android permission doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html there is no such permission at all.

I'm trying to build a app to monitor/intercept/change network traffic in Android, is that possible to do that without rooting the device?
TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible without a rooted device.

Answer (score 1):

The permission you're looking for is [WRITE_APN_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_APN_SETTINGS)

> "change/intercept network settings and traffic"
>
> "Allows an application to change network settings and to intercept and
>   inspect all network traffic, for example to change the proxy and port
>   of any APN. Malicious applications could monitor, redirect or modify
>   network packets without your knowledge."

Source: [http://androidxref.com/source/raw/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml](http://androidxref.com/source/raw/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml?r=2237e1e7b636651f0ed1efacefa8aaccb21433ca)